# Bug in Select your next badge pop up

Tags: bug, design, badges

There is a UI bug in Select your next badge pop up window.
The Description of a badge is been displayed in the box of badge below it.
Viewed in `Google chrome Version 48.0.2564.109 m`
**Please see images below:**

### [image: Image1]

### [image: Image2]

[image: Image3]